# (No active SparkContext.) Error submitting Job to local Spark master

Tags: java, apache-spark

I got a Spark Master and a Spark Slave up and running on my local Machine. I want to submit my code to my running Spark Master via command line configurations like this, just like described in the docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf());
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, BATCH_SIZE);
...
```

After building my .jar, i submit via

```
bin/spark-submit --class logAnalysis.myApp --name "myApp" --master "spark://some.server:7077" /jars/myApp-0.3.jar
```

Edit: I tried setting the master without quotes before.

After this, i get following Error:

```
17/03/22 12:23:02 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/03/22 12:23:04 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: Master removed our application: FAILED
17/03/22 12:23:04 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
logAnalysis.myApp.main(myApp.java:48)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

(No active SparkContext.)

        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getSchedulingMode(SparkContext.scala:1658)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postEnvironmentUpdate(SparkContext.scala:2162)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:542)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at logAnalysis.myApp.main(myApp.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
```

My Spark Master shows the job as failed in the job list, so i am sucessfully connecting to my Master.

when i do submit my job via

```
bin/spark-submit --class logAnalysis.myApp--name "myApp" --master local[8] /jars/myApp-0.3.jar
```

it works just fine.

Am using spark 2.0.2, my scala versions are not the problem, as stated in this thread: [Why is "Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext" thrown when connecting to Spark Standalone from Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606403/why-is-cannot-call-methods-on-a-stopped-sparkcontext-thrown-when-connecting-to)

Everything is kinda set up as default. Some suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: What about setting the master without the quotes on your first example, i.e. `spark://some.server:7077` (I don't believe it will work), but the documentation seems to never bother with quotes

Comment: i already tried this before, doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

I now have added another Node to my Cluster. It's sucessfully running now with 1x Master - 2x Worker Setup.

Didnt change anything in the Code besides adding the ElasticSearch-HadoopConnector to the Configuration:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().set("es.nodes", "node1").set("es.port", "9200"));
```

I dont know what the Problem was, maybe it was caused by the Config. But as said before, the job was successfully running when setting the Master to local[*].